# Replace "§" and the next char

Tags: php

I have a database and out of there I load Strings which contain the character "§", what turns out as "�" in the php script. Now I know how to remove these chars. I would have simply to use

```
mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8')
```

,but dear I have to remove the char after this "§", too.

The raw string may look like this:

```
�b18:23:47�7: �fTROOP3R kannst du dir das bitte anschauen
```

But it has to look like this:

```
18:23:47: TROOP3R kannst du dir das bitte anschauen
```

I hope that there exists a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work out:

```
/([^A-Za-z0-9 :])\w/g
```

Check out the working here:
http://regexr.com/3cs65

Paste : `�b18:23:47�7: �fTROOP3R kannst du dir das bitte anschauen` in the text area to see what all gets eliminated.

Comment: But in this case "�b18:23:47" will turn out as "b18:23:47", too and not as "18:23:47"

Comment: It worked, but only with "/([^A-Za-z0-9 :])\w/" without this g at the end. What shuld this be for?

Comment: Thank you very much. Look what you have helped me at: http://mcplayhd.net/chatlog.php?id=4n74zfp2r9

Comment: @NicolaUetz, its awesome. I feel privileged helping you. Good Luck ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104376/discussion-between-nicola-uetz-and-fakhruddin-ujjainwala).

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
$src = '§dsa §d§sa§ §dsa§';
echo $src . PHP_EOL;
echo preg_replace("/\xC2\xA7/", "", $src);
```

Output:

```
§dsa §d§sa§ §dsa§
dsa dsa dsa
```

I suppose you've got idea :) Convert required symbol to escape sequence and use it in regular expression.

Next char you can catch by regexp dot, like `.?` (question sign for end-line case).

Comment: No after preg_replace('/\xC2\xA7\w/', '', $splitted[$i]) the § haven't dissappeared... http://mcplayhd.net/cheatlog.php?id=402rr784